# Example CNF for FOL

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I don't understand this example: $\forall x [\forall y\ Animal(y)\Rightarrow Loves(x,y)] \Rightarrow [\exists\ y Loves(y,x)] \\$.

After, I must eliminate biconditionals and implications. In the example i have: $\forall x [\neg\forall y\ \neg Animal(y)\lor Loves(x,y)] \lor [\exists\ y Loves(y,x)] \\$.

I don't understand why when i eliminate the outermost implication, I don't have this situation: $\forall x \neg[\forall y\ \neg Animal(y)\lor Loves(x,y)] \lor [\exists\ y Loves(y,x)] \\$

I apply the rule: $\alpha\Rightarrow\beta$ replaced with $\neg\alpha\lor\beta$.

Comment: Although it's probably not confusing you here, you do need a couple of more pairs of parentheses/brackets to properly show the scope of the first two quantifiers. The first $\forall x$ should govern the entire formula, but as written it only governs the antecedent; the first $\exists y$ should govern the entire inner formula of the antecedent but as written only governs the, um, antecedent of the antecedent. In short, you should have $$\forall x [\forall y\ (Animal(y)\Rightarrow Loves(x,y))] \Rightarrow [\exists\ y Loves(y,x)]] $$

Comment: {In English: if $x$ loves every animal, then something loves $x$.} To form the CNF, it will probably help to change the second bound $y$ to, say, $z$, and then move all the quantifiers to the front, taking care to use the rule $\forall \neg \equiv \neg\exists$.

Comment: Thanks @BrianO. I have understand with the first explanation.

Comment: Adding parentheses & brackets helped, I imagine :) Good, & you're welcome. // Re my 2nd comment, really I should have mentioned the dual rule $\neg\forall\equiv\exists\neg$.